# Using Facebook SDK in Angular 2

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been reading this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

and I need to import the facebook SDK in order to use the following code:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

How I Can import the facebook SDK using Angular 2 app?

Answer (score 9):

No need to use facebook sdk we can use window location in same ts file as like below. And also we can do it same for any social media like twitter linkedin.

Facebook :

```
popupfacebook() {
    let url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+ this.shareLink;
       let newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=500,width=520,top=200,left=300,resizable');
  if (window.focus) {
      newwindow.focus()
  } 
}
```

Twitter:

```
popuptweet(){
       let url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+ this.shareLink;
       let newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=500,width=520,top=200,left=300,resizable');
  if (window.focus) {
      newwindow.focus()
}}
```

Linkedin :

```
popuplinkedin(){
      let url ='https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url='+this.shareLink;
       let newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=500,width=520,top=200,left=300,resizable');
  if (window.focus) {
      newwindow.focus()
  }
}
```

Comment: a better solution than using any package.

Comment: There is any similar way to share with Instagram ? thanks

Comment: People come here looking for a solution to the isolated problem of integrating the Facebook SDK with Angular. You completely fail to provide an answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

After three days of research found solution for facebook sharing with dynamic content

in index.html:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta name="fbDescription" property="og:description" content="desc">
<meta name="fbJobTitle" property="og:title" content="title">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="ur app id" />
<meta name="fbImage" property="og:image" content="url">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site name" />
```

Install npm package

```
npm i --save ngx-facebook
```

In your app.module

```
import { FacebookModule } from 'ngx-facebook';
imports:[FacebookModule.forRoot()]   // donot forget to add
```

in your service or component add

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
providers: [ApiService, CommonDataService, FacebookService]

constructor(private fbk: FacebookService){
fbk.init({
    appId: 'yourappid', cookie: true, status: true, xfbml: true, version: 'v2.8'
  });
 }
  (function (d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id))
    return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

in your button click function add

```
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'website' });
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'websitename' });
          this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: 'title'});
          this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: 'Description'});
          this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: 'url' });

  this.fbk.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      object: {
        'og:title': 'title',
        'og:description': 'description',
        'og:image': 'imagelink',
        'og:url': referlink,
      }
    })
  });
```

reference url : http://drib.tech/programming/dynamically-change-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-javascript

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This is working for me. Have you tried sharing on business page which you manage? It will work only for profile page.

Comment: It works for sharing dynamic content but I did not try with business page.

Comment: Yes. It is not working for business page. Please share once you have any information.

Comment: Hello @Priya, You find any solution for fb share issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get access inside your any.component.ts file you'll need get a  `window` referece (Iam using the follwing code):

```
function _window():any {
  return window;
}

export class WindowRef {
    public static get():any {
        return _window();
    }
}
```

Now you can:

```
import { WindowRef } from './windowRef';

export class AnyComponent {
   WindowRef.get().FB.ui // <-- this is how you'll reference it now
}
```

You'll need to make sure, that the `FB` Object is availabe on `window`. Afterwards your code will transpile.

Comment: Could you explain this more in deep? where to put the firt block of code? and why this should work?

Comment: The first block would be an own file (i called it windowRef.js). And it contains a importable class (see second block). But you can do this in an easier way. Put "declare var window;" right after the imports inside the file where you'll need access to the FB.ui function. You then should be able to call window.FB.ui because FB is an object of window. Another way may be to use "declare var FB;" and directly access the according function, but Iam not sure about that. For explanation the window object represents the global scope from there you can access all global vars.

Comment: Declaring FB variable works for me i.e.

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare let FB: any;