# Meta tag is not updated in(View source code) in angular9

Tags: angular, facebook-javascript-sdk, server-side-rendering, meta-tags, angular-universal

I'm implementing a Facebook button that posts dynamic content on Facebook, But it only takes static URL as given in (index.html page) meta-tag.

```html
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="app_id" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="url" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="My App" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Test the site" />
    <meta
      property="og:image"
      content="image_url"
    />
```

When i use updateTag for meta data it's update in inspect not in view page source. My update tag code is ->

```js
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'article' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'New-SiteName' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: 'New-Title' });
    this.meta.updateTag({
      property: 'og:description',
      content: 'New-description',
    });
    this.meta.updateTag({
      property: 'og:image',
      content:
        'new-image-url',
    });

    this.fbk.ui({
      method: 'share_open_graph',
      action_type: 'og.shares',
      action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
          'og:title': 'New-Title',
          'og:description': 'New-Description',
          'og:image':
            'imageUrl',
          'og:url': 'redirect_url',
          },
         }),
      });
```

I refer -
[Using Facebook SDK in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645501/using-facebook-sdk-in-angular-2/51723867#51723867)

Also, I used Angular universal from angular.io for SSR but still facing the same issue.

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You can not update the meta tags client-side only; the HTML returned by each individual URL must contain the appropriate meta data right away – the Facebook scraper does not care for any client-side JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your comment, is there any other solution to post dynamic content on Facebook and on Instagram?